# ImageMagickコマンドで、画像に青色を上塗り後、白色文字を追加描画したい

Tags: imagemagick

ImageMagickコマンドで、下記それぞれは実行できたのですが、
・画像に色を上塗りすること。[画像に色を上塗りする](http://image-magick.com/2014/09/25/colorize/)
・画像に白色文字を追加描画すること。[ImageMagickで画像に文字を描画](https://tech.mktime.com/entry/145)

両方を一度に行うことができません。
-fill で色を指定すると、画像と追加描画文字に同じ色が指定されてしまいます。

例えば、画像に青色を追加して(`convert origin.jpg -fill blue -colorize 50` )、白色文字も追加(`convert -font Arial.ttf  -background none -fill white`)するためにはどうすればよいですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

※ TrueType フォントのパスは適宜変更してください。

```bash
convert \( origin.jpg -fill blue -colorize 50 \) \
  \( -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf -background none -fill white -pointsize 32 label:Sample \) \
  -gravity center -compose over -composite sample.jpg
```

**sample.jpg**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 期待通り動作しました。